# Swift contextual type any cannot be used with array literal

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a new class with parameters for requests and I am getting an error:

> contextual type any cannot be used with array literal

I tried to add `as Any` at the end, but it won't work.

```
class JsonParams {
    let userName = "root"
    let password = "admin01"

    static let param: [String: Any] = [
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "call",
        "params": [
            "00000000000000000000000000000000",
            "session",
            "login",
            [ "username": userName, "password": password]
        ]
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now I need to send the username and password to param from username text field after somebody types it, so I want to make a method for param,

```
class JsonParams {

let userName = "root"
let password = "admin01"
var param = [String: Any]()
func log (username.text, password.text){
init() {
    let param : [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", [ "username": username.text, "password": password.text]]]
    self.param = param
}
```

Comment: The `text` property of a text field is an optional, you need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to initialise objects this way:

```
class JsonParams {

    let userName = "root"
    let password = "admin01"
    var param = [String: Any]()

    init() {
        let param : [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", [ "username": self.userName, "password": self.password]]]
        self.param = param
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get `userName` you can do it this way:

```
class JsonParams {

    let userName = "root"
    let password = "admin01"
    var param = [String: Any]()

    init() {
        let param : [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ "00000000000000000000000000000000", "session", "login", [ "username": self.userName, "password": self.password]]]
        self.param = param
    }

    func getUserName() -> String {

        return self.userName
    }
}
```

And this way you can access:

```
let json = JsonParams()
json.getUserName()  //"root"
```

Comment: Hey I need a little bit more help, I need to make a method inside this class, which get username and password, I tried to add func but I get error.class                                                                                    JsonParams {
func (username, password, Login_Token){
    
    
    var param = [String: Any]()
    
    init() {
        let param : [String: Any] = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [ self.Login_Token, "session", "login", [ "username": self.userName, "password": self.password]]]
        self.param = param
    }
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, but I think you didnt get me. I edu=ited my question.

Answer (score 15):

#### General answer for future visitors

This type of error can happen when you try to assign an array to something that is not an array.

**Example 1**

```
let array: Int = [1, 3, 7, 4]
// error: contextual type Int cannot be used with array literal
```

Contrary to its name, the constant `array` is stated to be a single `Int`. But then an actual array is assigned to it. This can be fixed by either of the following ways.

```
let array = [1, 3, 7, 4]
let array: [Int] = [1, 3, 7, 4]
```

**Example 2**

It can be less obvious when there are nested arrays:

```
let array: [Int] = [1, 2, 7, [100, 200, 300]]
// error: contextual type Int cannot be used with array literal
```

For this one you would need to generalize it to `[Any]`.

```
let array: [Any] = [1, 2, 7, [100, 200, 300]]
```

Comment: Thanks. For a better debugging mindset in the future: I'm curious what does `contextual type` mean? If something isn't contextual type then what type is it?

Comment: @Honey, I take it to mean that according to the context it was expecting one type (an `Int` in this case), but it found a different type (an array). I don't think it means that there is something defined as a "contextual type". In Swift there are only [two kinds of types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html): named types and compound types.